# A Complex Inputs Form in CodeIgniter - Data for Three Tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, input

I have the following three tables:

```
ADDRESSES
------------
// Usual Address Data Fields

People
-------------
// Usual Personal Info
AddressId - FK
RoleId - FK

Role
--------------
RoleId
Name
```

One Role can have many People, and each Person shall only belong in one Role. As for the addresses, Each Person will be linked to one address, and each address will only be assigned to one person.

So, what I want to do is Register a Person. The Registration form must gather data for all three tables and store them in a way that won't make MySQL throw errors.

My form looks nice, and I have the Roles populating a drop down. But my question is regarding the handling of the POST request that arrives when the form is submitted. Here is my POST handling code:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('FirstName', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('LastName', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Telephone', 'Telephone', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('MaxNo', 'MaxNo', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('FirstLine', 'First Line', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('SecondLine', 'Second Line', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('City', 'City', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PostCode', 'Post Code', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        echo "Validation Failed";
        // something went wrong.
        $this->load->model('rolesmodel');
        $data['roles'] = $this->rolesmodel->getRolesForUserRegForm();
        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('charity/register', $data);
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');
    } else {
        // All is Good

        $address = array(
            'FirstLine' => $this->input->post('FirstLine'),
            'SecondLine' => $this->input->post('SecondLine'),
            'City' => $this->input->post('City'),
            'PostCode' => $this->input->post('PostCode'),
        );

        $this->load->model('addresses_model');
        $addId = $this->addresses_model->getCurrentCountOfRows();

        $this->addresses_model->addNewsAddress($address);

         $person = array(
            'FirstName' => $this->input->post('FirstName'),
            'LastName' => $this->input->post('LastName'),
            'Telephone' => $this->input->post('Telephone'),
            'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
            'Password' => $this->input->post('Password'),
            'MaxNo' => $this->input->post('MaxNo'),
            'AddressId' => (int)$addId + 1,
            'RoleId' => $this->input->post('Name') // this is the Roles DropDown Name Property
        );

        $this->load->model('people_model');
        $this->people_model->registerPerson($person);
        redirect('/animals/index');
    }
}
```

I know I have to save the address into the database first, but if I do so, how can I then quickly grab its ID? Cause it won't have an ID unless it firsts saves into the database.

Secondly, how can I handle the Role drop down choice?

Comment: why sould the address first ??

Comment: because the Person references the Address. If the Address is not in the database, it cannot reference it .. No?

Comment: address is inputted by user(I see your code), right?

Comment: Yep, the address will be supplied by the user. Here's what the form [looks like](https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/213/pethomeform.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your addres ID after insert, make the function in the model return:

```
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

To get your dropdown value, in you view you'll have a select. Something like this probably:

```
<select name="roleId">....</select>
```

Use this to get your roleId in your controller:

```
$person->RoleId = $this->input->post('roleId')
```

Note that the string you put in the post() method has to accord with the 'name' attribute of your select

Change your code at the end to this:

```
$this->load->model('PeopleModel');
$this->load->model('AddressModel');
$person->AddressId = $this->AddressModel->insert($address);
$this->PeopleModel->register($person);
```

Hope this helps, don't hesitate to ask further questions =)

Comment: Thanks About the ID @Crowlix. Just about to try it now. As for the Dropdown, I knew how to populate, I just don't know how to handle it at the POST side of things. :)

Comment: Got that problem fixed, but still need help with the drop down and how to handle it in the Controller's POST handling function

Comment: Thanks, it got me closer to the solution, then I figured it. I needed the Role ID and not the Role Name. So I created a new function to grab the ID from the Name on my `roles_model`. I then called it like so `(int)$this->roles_model->getRoleIdFromName($this->input->post('Name'))`. Now it all works :)

Answer (score 1):

I will do it simply like: (this is must be your register function, just pseudo-code )

```
 protected function getAddressId($param = array()){
    //save address data here and return it's id;     
 }

 public function register($param = array()){
   //1. grab address id
   $AdsressId = $this->getAddressId()
   //2. save person data + $AddressId + RoleId
   //3. All done
 }
```

Comment: This was my original line of thinking too, but then I thought there might be a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: I can't test that code, cause validation fails before I reach the interesting bits. :( Any idea why it would fail to validate? I am typing everything correctly (I think!). Also the Validation Error messages are not showing, even thought I have this on my view. `<?php validation_errors(); ?>`

Comment: mmm.. have no idea, try to activate log_threshold maybe helping.

Comment: The validation was failing because I was doing this `$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE` ! There is no need to equate to false, since statement already returns boolean. All is working now except DropDown value. I'll have a play around with that to try and fix it.

Comment: :) thanks to let me know. whats the problem about Dropdown value?